# R Studio application issues

Tags: rstudio

I am having an issue installing R studio. It shows up in my doc on the bottom of my mac although when i click on it nothing happens. I have also tried to uninstall it by dragging the icon to the trash although it doesn't allow me to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-r-and-rstudio-on-mac-e911606ce4f4  this documentation

Comment: I believe i actually have the applications (R and R studio) downloaded, but R studio will not open when i click on it. In this case i think i need help completely uninstalling the app which does not work when i drag it to the trash.

Comment: Please see this documentation https://www.minicreo.com/mac-uninstaller/uninstall-rstudio-mac.html here you can get information to uninstall rstudio . If you already tried this let me know

Comment: If you installed R to a non-default location, it is possible RStudio cannot find R on your machine. Open a standard console session (RGui, R.app, Terminal, etc) and type the following command at the console:

> Sys.which("R")